# I am trying to remove a single value from a MultiMap(org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap) in JAVA

Tags: java, collections, graph, hashmap

I am trying to remove a single value from a MultiMap (org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap) in Java. The issue is it contains two values. When I remove one, the other gets removed as well.

```
class MappedValue
{
  public MappedValue(String id , boolean touched) {
    identifier = id;
    this.touched=touched;
  }

  private String  identifier;  
  private boolean touched; 
}   

MultiMap SuccessorsArray = new MultiValueMap();   

MappedValue mv = new MappedValue("1", false);
MappedValue mv2 = new MappedValue("2", true);

SuccessorsArray.put("key1", mv );         
SuccessorsArray.put("key1", mv2 );      
//Below is the problem as both values in the get removed instead of 1(mv).
SuccessorsArray.remove("key1", mv);
```

Comment: why not removing with using key alone . e.g SuccessorsArray.remove("key1");

Comment: He don't want to remove both key/value. He want to remove `"key1"/mv` and keep `"key1"/mv2`.

Comment: @romfret is right. Only one of the key-value pairs gets removed.

Comment: @romfet removeMapping does not work on me, perhaps you can tell me the library you using, am unsing org.apache.commons.collections.MultiMap

Comment: The latest version I found on mavenrepository : 
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
 <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Am using API 3.2.1 , thanks for asking

Comment: Ok, sorry, my fault.

Comment: Arent you using Google's guava?

Comment: I will try, once more.

Comment: Probably better to use Guava's Multimap which actually works :)

Comment: Let me upgrade to apache's version 4 and retry.

Comment: Wow, apaches multimap has no generics? Better use guava ;).

Comment: @Tom It have generics in version 4 ;)

Comment: @romfret good to hear. But I still would recommend Guava :D.

Comment: @Walker You can keep the version 3, just take a look at my answer ;)

Comment: For now, then I will need the upgrade later. I think  removeMapping(key,value) sounds more intuitive.

Comment: I don't think it's more intuitive, on the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested with 3.2.1 version and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class MappedValue {
        public MappedValue(String id, boolean touched) {
            identifier = id;
            this.touched = touched;
        }
        private String identifier;
        private boolean touched;
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MappedValue [identifier=" + identifier + ", touched=" + touched + "]";
        }
    }

    MultiMap multiMap = new MultiValueMap();
    MappedValue mv = new MappedValue("1", false);
    MappedValue mv2 = new MappedValue("2", true);
    multiMap.put("key1", mv);
    multiMap.put("key1", mv2);
    //Below is the problem as both values in the get removed instead of 1(mv).
    multiMap.remove("key1", mv);
    System.out.println(multiMap.get("key1"));
}
```

returns `[MappedValue [identifier=2, touched=true]]`

so the value is indeed not removed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
MultiValueMap SuccessorsArray = new MultiValueMap();
```

instead of

```
MultiMap SuccessorsArray = new MultiValueMap();
```

I tested it, it works, with version `3.2.1` of `commons-collection`.

By the way, you should not name your Map `SuccessorsArray` but `successorsArray`.

Comment: removeMapping("key1", mv);  doesnot work unfortunately. Its actually not an available method for the object...

Comment: @Walker I don't understand why you marked the other answer as accepted, but anyway, you're welcome.

Comment: @refret, your output showed that its what I would like to have . By the way I just upgraded to version 4. Thanks again for sharing.